# C# ServiceStack OrmLite, how to read all records with references

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

var entities = await db.LoadSelectAsync(_ => true);
Is there a way to do this without sending a param? something like a LoadSelectAll()? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can select from an empty `SqlExpression<T>` without any filter conditions, e.g:

```cs
var entities = await db.LoadSelectAsync(db.From<Table>());
```